# How can I filter in the kubernetes API (or kubectl) for Jobs owned by a given CronJob?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have several CronJobs, and I want to be able to query for a list of completed jobs for a specific one. I tried `--field-selector metadata.ownerReferences.uid` but that's not a supported field selector for batchv1.job (Looking at [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/batch/v1/conversion.go#L40-L50) it appears there are no useful field selectors for this use case).

I don't completely understand the DownwardAPI, but I was wondering if i can set a label on the job_spec (in the cronjob definition) that references the cronjobs uid, so I can then use label selectors to filter. I can't tell if thats possible.

Filtering for jobs by owner seems like a reasonable thing to be able to do, but I can't seem to find any useful information when searching around.

Comment: All cronjobs have unique names so the easiest way to display all jobs belonging to a certain cronjob is by using `kubectl get jobs | grep cronjob-name`. Individual job name always starts from cronjob name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We're using generateName to create the job names, so as an example it might be `daily-backup-`, and kubernetes will generate a name of `daily-backup-12345`. But then if i have another CronJob with generateName of `daily-backup-12345-` ...theres a potential for overlap of the prefix. Its *really* unlikely at least for my use case, but I'd prefer to have a real relationship to match on, such as the one I mentioned: metadata.ownerReferences.uid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this two commands to get a list of jobs belonging to a Cronjob:

```
uid=$(kubectl get cronjob [MY-CRONJOB-NAME] --output jsonpath='{.metadata.uid}')
kubectl get jobs -o json | jq -r --arg uid "$uid" '.items | map(select(.metadata.ownerReferences[]? | .uid==$uid) | .metadata.name) | .[]'
```

The first command fetches the `metadata.uid` from your specified `[MY-CRONJOB-NAME]`. Then, a `kubectl get` all jobs, and the output is processed with [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to filter them by the `.metadata.ownerReferences.uid`.

---

If you want a more simple approach, you can play with the `--custom-columns`  flag. The following example list all jobs and their respective controller names:

```
kubectl get jobs --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CONTROLLER:.metadata.ownerReferences[].name,NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I should have been more clear in my question. I was hoping to do the filtering on the server side. We will potentially have a large number of cronjobs, and with each we'll retain a handful of the completed jobs, so filtering client-side won't be very efficient.

To add some more details, I'm using the `generateName` feature so I don't have to manually name each cronjob we create. I guess another idea is to have our application generate the name of the job and then toss that in the JobSpec as a label so we can take advantage of label selectors to retrieve the jobs.

Comment: One more note, the `ownerReferences` piece of the Job metadata is apparently used for GarbageCollection. Which I assume means that some internal kubernetes pieces are able to look up jobs based on those fields. I'm just wondering if anything is available via the kubernetes API. I might just open a feature request in kubernetes explaining my use case.

Comment: @JoeCeresini Please consider editing your initial question or posting a new one.

Comment: It seemed clear there wasn't a solution for exactly what I was hoping to do, so instead I opened a feature request for kubernetes: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/84493